# Application Usage Time Tracking Application for IOS with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, usagestatsmanager

I am developing an application with React native that shows how much time users spend on other applications on the phone.

I can access this data using the react-native-usage-stats package for Android. But I could not find any package for IOS. Frankly, I could not find any documentation or an example of how to do it. Is there a method you can recommend?

Comment: This information is not available to apps on iOS. It would be a privacy violation and the information is available to the user already in settings

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am developing an application that will be used for education with the users' approval. I need this application to track how much time students spend on their phones, create a report about it, and present it to their teachers. And I saw that similar applications are available in the AppStore. If there was a privacy vulnerability, I think AppStore would detect it.

Comment: You can use [DeviceActivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeviceActivity) to set policy and generate reports but the usage data will not be available to your app.